# jQuery.load() with AJAX Kontactr form

Tags: jquery, load, inline-scripting

After seeing many questions about how jQuery.load() handles  tags in the content to be loaded, I see that jQuery strips out inline  tags. But, I'd like to use [Kontactr](http://kontactr.com/) for the contact page in my site, and the much nicer AJAX embed they have is two script tags as in the code examples below. How can I work around the jQuery.load() constraints to make these script tags run in the jQuery.load(file, callback()) callback() function?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--include css, jquery, scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#main_content').load('contact.html #main_content', function(){
                //what can I put here to run the Kontactr inline script code
                //when contact.html is loaded?
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_content"><!--content will load here--></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**contact.html**

```
<div id="main_content">
    <h1>Please Contact Us With The Form Below</h1>
    <!-- jQuery.load will strip out these script tags 
         and the form will not be embedded. -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> id = 1; </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kontactr.com/wp.js"></script>
</div>
```

I've thought maybe I can put a `<div id="contact_form"/>` in contact.html and then maybe eval the script tags in the callback function inside of
 `$('#contact_form').html(//eval script tags result here);`, but I'm not sure how to do that syntactically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in case anyone else runs into this issue, there's a pretty simple solution.

That http://kontactr.com/wp.js script just document.write()s an iframe to the page. What I wound up doing was this:

```
<div id="main_content">
    <h1>Please Contact Us With The Form Below</h1>
    <center>
        <iframe id="kontactr-iframe" src="http://kontactr.com/w.php?id=1&referrer=http://www.theurlyourrequestingfrom.com&color=000000-FFFFFF-000000-FFFFFF" width="475px" height="475px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </center>
</div>
```

It works like a charm.

Notes: The `color` argument is optional, and the `id` argument is specific to your Kontactr account. The `referrer` argument is populated with `window.top.location.href` in the http://kontactr.com/wp.js script. I just put the URL of the $.load() page there.